# Не привильно работает запись данных в json

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

При успешно вводе тел номера в инпут, данные о вводе (номер тел и дата ) записываются в json . Но если стереть инпут и ввести туда номер повторно , то данные запишутся два раза . То-есть, с каждым удалением номера данные запишутся всё больше раз. Ошибку не могу найти . Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию?

Вот код :

```
 function checkValid() {
    var val = $("#phone").val();
    var enable = true;
    var valid = false;    
       if (!val || val.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 12){ enable = false;}
       if (codes[val.substr(5, 3)]){ valid = true;}

        if (!enable || !valid) {
                        $('.error').text('Некорректный ввод');
                        $("#call").attr("disabled","disabled");
                    }else{

                        $('.error').text('');

                    }

          if (enable &&  valid) { $("#call").removeAttr("disabled");
                     var retite = new Date();

                        $('#call').click(function(){         
                            obj = {
                            dates: 'дата',
                            time: 'время',
                            phone: phone
                        };
                        obj['date'] = retite
                        alert(obj['date']);

                      });            



          }
}
```

Чтоб было понятно о чём я толкую, вот полный код : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/44/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. При вызове функции checkValid на кнопку "Заказать звонок", каждый раз вешается все новый обработчик события ее нажатия, причем, старые никуда не исчезают.

   ```
   function checkValid() {
   ...
   $('#call').click(function(){
   ```
2. В переменной phone которая записывается в объект находится DOM элемент, а не введенный выше номер телефона.